# Understanding the steps in Pugh's proof about the Least Upper Bound Property

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, order-theory

> **2 Theorem**
>
> The set $\Bbb R$, constructed by means of Dedekind cuts, is complete in the sense that it satisfies the
>
> ***Least Upper Bound Property***:If $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\Bbb R$ and is bounded above then in $\Bbb R$ there exists a least upper bound for $S$.
>
> **Proof**: Easy! Let $\mathcal C\subset\Bbb R$ be any nonempty collection of cuts which is bounded above, say by the cut $X | Y$.
> Define
> $C:=\{a\in\Bbb Q:\text{ for some cut } A | B\in\mathcal C\text{ we have } a\in A\}$ and $D=$ the rest of $\Bbb Q$.
> [image]
> **source**: *Real Mathematical Analysis* by Pugh.

I'm trying to make sense of the significance of the sentence beginning with "By the assumption that ...". How does Pugh go from that sentence to making the conclusion that $C$ is a subset of $C'$? How does this show that $C$ is a subset of $C'$? Doesn't the sentence still hold if we replaced every instance of $C'$ with $C$? That is, "By the assumption that $A|B\leq C|D$ for all $A|B\in ℭ$, we see that the $A$ for every member of $ℭ$ is contained in $C$? Maybe im misunderstanding the sentence's purpose but I'm not seeing its significance nor how it ties into the his conclusion that $C$ is a subset of $C'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof has two steps:

1. $\text{Show that } z \text{ is an upper bound}.$
2. $\text{Show that } z \text{ is less than any other upper bound.}$

It's useful to note that by the construction of $z = C|D$ we have $C = \bigcup_{A|B\in \cal{C}}A$. In words: $C$ is the union of all the $A$'s from $\cal{C}$. Recall that $A|B \leq A^{\prime}|B^{\prime}$ if and only if $A \subseteq A^{\prime}$. It follows that $A|B \leq z$ for all $A|B \in \cal{C}$, which is exactly what it means for $z$ to be an upper bound. So this takes care of step 1.

For step 2 we have to show that $z$ in addition to being an upper bound in fact is a *least* upper bound. We do this by considering any other upper bound $z^{\prime}$ and showing that $z \leq z^{\prime}$. We write $z^{\prime} = C^{\prime}| D^{\prime}$ and what we need to show is that $C \subseteq C^{\prime}$. We have assumed that $z^{\prime}$ is an upper bound for $\cal{C}$ hence $A|B \leq z^{\prime}$ for all $A|B \in \cal{C}$, which means that $A \subseteq C^{\prime}$ for all $A|B \in \cal{C}$. Since $C^{\prime}$ contains all the $A$s, $C^{\prime}$ also contains their union: $\bigcup_{A|B\in \cal{C}}A \subseteq C^{\prime}$. But as we noted above this union is equal to $C$. So in fact we have shown $C \subseteq C^{\prime}$, that is : $z\leq z^{\prime}$. This takes care of step 2.